# Custom to do app not accessible from menu

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I'm new at odoo. Reading "Odoo 12 Development Essential, 4th Edition". However, I've installed Odoo 15 in AWS EC2 Instance.

Followed the books steps to create To-Do app in odoo. But its not showing in menu and I can't use it. What have I don't wrong?

1. First created "To-Do Item" model and added some extra fields
2. Created "To-do User" group and added "User Types/Internal User" in
   'Inherited' Tab. Also give read/write/delete/create access to "To-do
   Item" Model in "Access Rights" Tab.
3. Then added admin user to  "To-do User" group.

Now as per the books, admin should be able to create To-do Items and all from menu.
But this item isn't available in menu. What have I done wrongly?

Answer (score 1):

maybe odoo didn`t update your module, because there were some issues.
I had the same problem before, do next:
Activate developer mode in settings.
Then go to settings → technical → security rules. Find and check your access rights and record rules, maybe odoo didnt update it.
if all is right, then go to technical → interface → menu items.
find your menu record and check, if there is your group.
if all is right, maybe app is not app, check that there is a

```
    'installable': True,
    'application': True,
```

parameters in manifest file.

and also for example menuitems from odoo 15 docs:

```
<menuitem id="estate_root" name="Нерухомість">
    <menuitem id="estate_objects" name="Об'єкти нерухомості">
        <menuitem id="menuitem_estate_property" action="estate_property_action"/>
    </menuitem>
    <menuitem id="estate_settings" name="Налаштування">
        <menuitem id="menuitem_estate_property_type_id" action="estate_property_type_action"/>
        <menuitem id="menuitem_estate_property_tag_id" action="estate_property_tag_action"/>
    </menuitem>
</menuitem>
```

first item in this example is root item

*P.S. if your dont see your app in apps settings, you need to push button "Update apps list"

*P.S.2 check, if there is your file in manifest data:

```
'data': [
    'security/ir.model.access.csv',
    'views/estate_property_views.xml',
],
```

Comment: Actually I've added a module using gui. Not adding any manifes file and adding custom module. Thanks btw for answer.